# "¿Por qué CodeIgniter 4 no reporta un error al actualizar una columna ENUM con un valor inválido?"

Tags: codeigniter-4

Tengo un campo de la tabla `persona` `tipo_documento enum('CI','CIE','DNI','PASAPORTE')` cuando ejecuto esta consulta

```
UPDATE `persona` SET `tipo_documento` = 'EMUMDFDSFDS'
WHERE `persona`.`id` IN (39996)
```

evidentemente me da el error `SQL Error [1265] [01000]: (conn=258) Data truncated for column 'tipo_documento' at row 1`

pero por alguna extraña razon Codeigniter 4 no reporta el error

```
var_dump($personaModel->update($idPersonaDecrypted, ['tipo_documento' => 'EMUMDFDSFDS']));
```

es decir imprime `bool(true)` y tambien actualiza tipo_documento a (vacio) no entiendo la razón